# jQuery error: Message: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #

Tags: jquery

This is the error that I get when I try to run the [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) code below:

> Message: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
>
> URI: /..///jquery-1.7.2.min.js
>
> jquery-1.7.2.min.js

However, it works fine when JavaScript is turned off. What might the problem be?

#### jQuery code

```
function setUpArticleToolsList() {
    $("#articleToolsList").before("<span id='articleToolsButton' class='button article-tools tool-tip tt-top' title='View Chapter Tools' data-tool-tip='View Chapter Tools'><span>Chapter Tools</span></span>");
    $("#articleToolsList").append("<li><span id='closeTools' class='close' title='close tools'><span>close</span></span></li>");
    var titleHeight = $(".article-title").height();
    $("#articleToolsList").hide();

    $("#articleToolsButton").show();
    $("#articleToolsButton").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        if (titleHeight < 95) { //Only animate to 95 pixels depth if smaller.
            $(".article-title").animate({
                height: 95}, function(){
                $("#articleToolsList").show();
            });
        }
        else {
            $("#articleToolsList").show();
        }
    });
    $("#closeTools").click(function(){
        $("#articleToolsButton").show();
        $("#articleToolsList").hide();
        if (titleHeight < 95) {
            $(".article-title").animate({
                height: titleHeight});
        }
    });
```

Comment: How can it works fine with js off?

Comment: you have some code after this function? post your complete code please

Comment: function close curly bracket `{` is missing here.. is it a typo .. ??

Comment: you are missing a closing bracket at the very end of your code

Comment: I don't know why everyone doesn't line up their brackets in columns to avoid errors like this.